# Hive: Is there a performance improvement of using where clause in subtables before joins?

Tags: sql, performance, join, hive, where-clause

I want to join 2 hive tables. Is there a performance difference between following statements?

Columns for basic_info: user_id, name, lastname, birthday, occupation

Columns for account_info: user_id, account_id, type, balance

Query1:

```
SELECT b.user_id, a.account_id, b.name, b.lastname, a.balance
FROM account_info a
JOIN basic_info b
   ON a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE b.occupation = 'lawyer'
```

Query2:

```
SELECT b.user_id, a.account_id, b.name, b.lastname, a.balance
FROM account_info a
JOIN 
   (SELECT user_id, name, lastname 
    FROM basic_info
    WHERE occupation = 'lawyer') b
   ON a.user_id = b.user_id
```

To me 2nd one looks more performant. But I couldn't find an obvious statement saying that. Closest thing I have found in Apache's website was:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins

> Joins occur BEFORE WHERE CLAUSES. So, if you want to restrict the OUTPUT of a join, a requirement should be in the WHERE clause, otherwise it should be in the JOIN clause. A big point of confusion for this issue is partitioned tables.

But the example it was given was for partitions not for this case. Is there an official document suggesting Query 2 is better or not?

Comment: What is the execution time of both queries? That ought to be a measurable way to answer your question.

Comment: On a modern relational database like mysql or oracle these two queries should generate exactly the same execution plan. Generally selection happens before the join. I am not sure about Hive. Best is to try to see the actual execution plans.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Query-2 should run fast. As you have mentioned, join occurs before where clause.

But to your question on official document- 
There is a Predicate push down option in Hive. By default this option is set to false. It can be set to true using

> set hive.optimize.ppd=true;

When this option is set to true the join occurs after where clause. In your case, if you set this property to 'True', both your queries should finish at the same time. When the property is set to false (default behavior) query 2 should finish quick.

Since HIVE has a explicit property for predicate push down, we can conclude that Join occurs before where clause when the property is set to false.

Comment: Predicate push is enabled by default for ages

hive.optimize.ppd
Default Value: true
Added In: Hive 0.4.0 with HIVE-279, default changed to true in Hive 0.4.0 with HIVE-626
Whether to enable predicate pushdown (PPD).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to write this sql. Although, your both queries return same output but internally execution plan differs and it may have significant difference in execution time. 
Hive [**explain command**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Explain) is good point to start with the debugging and understanding query execution plan behind the scene. I hope explain command will help you to figure out the differece between both commands.

Other factors, Hive [**Map Joins** and **SMB(Sort-Merge-Bucket)**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+JoinOptimization) improve efficiency of joins.